# What sizes and units should be used for creating iPhone wallpapers?

Tags: sketch-app, pixel, ios, iphone, retina

I was following [the sizes listed here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions), and I've been creating the artboards with the sizes in points, but should I be creating them with the size for rendered pixels instead? Furthermore, I believe Sketch use points but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the page you linked to says, the point units are an abstract system for determining coordinates; they don't directly correspond to pixels on a screen but give a convenient coordinate space across devices; so you can have an icon that is always 40 × 40 pt even though it is rendered at different pixel sizes on different devices.

If you're creating raster images (i.e. made of pixels at a specific size) then you want to make your images at the actual pixel size of the screen. Namely;

- 320 × 480 pixels for original iPhones
- 640 × 960 pixels for iPhone 4/4S
- 640 × 1136 pixels for iPhone 5/5S
- 750 × 1334 pixels for iPhone 6/6S/7
- 1080 × 1920 pixels for iPhone 6/6S/7 Plus

The reason Sketch would (I assume, I don't actually use Sketch) use points is because it works with vectors. If you're working *exclusively* with vectors then all that really matters is the proportions of the image; so you can work in points (or any other size/unit in the correct proportions; points are just convenient) to create assets to be used across multiple devices and output at the correct pixel sizes when needs be.

Comment: Just a suggestion... explaining that it's the *proportion* of the graphic/image which is more important working in vectors may be beneficial. I'm not a Sketch user either and I couldn't add anything more to your answer other than this. +1

Comment: @Metis sure, that's a good point. I'll add something when I've got a bit more time later on

Comment: iPhone Xs are _weird_ (1125 x 2436).

Answer (score 0):

Make them FullHD, 1080x1920 in pixels. Forget the pt unit in this case.

Comment: This would be the same size for all the iPhones from 2g-7+?

Answer (score -3):

1136 x 640. this is the standard size of iphone and if you want to know exactly Capture the screen shot and bring it in photoshop there is the accurate size.